# slideToggle() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `slideToggle()` method to hide and reveal some of the long content on my website but the issue iis that it is not working properly. When clicked on Load more the hidden element's css should change from `display:none;` to `display:block;` but it wont change and the element remains hidden. I have included my code below.

```
<div class="categories">
    <span class="acc_trigger pull-right btn">Load more</span>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="sub-categories sec block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Winery</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".acc_container > div").hide();
        jQuery(".categories span").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).siblings(".acc_container > div").slideToggle();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: there is no `.accordion` element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jm6bx7gv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method allows us to search through the siblings of these elements in the DOM tree.

You need to use

```
jQuery(this).siblings(".acc_container").find('div')
```

instead of

```
jQuery(this).siblings(".acc_container > div")
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".acc_container > div").hide();
  jQuery(".categories span").click(function() {
    var div = jQuery(this).siblings(".acc_container").find('div');
    div.slideToggle();
    $(this).text(div.is(':visible') ? 'Load less' : 'Load more');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories">
  <span class="acc_trigger pull-right btn">Load more</span>
  <div class="acc_container">
    <div class="sub-categories sec block">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Button</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Button</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#">Winery</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
jQuery(".categories span").click(function() {
    var div = jQuery(this).siblings(".acc_container").find('div');
    div.slideToggle();
    $(this).text(div.is(':visible') ? 'Load less' : 'Load more');
});
```

Comment: this fixed the issue. IS there any way to change the **Load more** text to change to **Load less** when the hidden element has been revealed?